# Getting "server certificate is a CA certificate" for my self-signed cert on Apache

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, configuration, mac-osx, apache2

I'm using Apache 2.2 on Mac High Sierra.  I would like to have my little local server have a self signed certificate for my domain.  SO I ran this command

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout cnote_devbox_com_key.pem -x509 -days 3650 -out cnote_devbox_com_cert.pem
```

and the VirtualHost directive to my httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mylocalhost.devbox.com
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/mywebproject
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/cnote_devbox_com_cert.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/cnote_devbox_com_key.pem"

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/mywebproject>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <LocationMatch "/proxy">
        ProxyPass "wss://127.0.0.1:8000"
        ProxyPassReverse "wss://127.0.0.1:8000"
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

but when I restart the server I get the below warning.

```
[Mon Mar 19 15:20:25.222028 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 48351] AH01906: mylocalhost.devbox.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
```

Not sure what this means but since I'm getting some other errors with my application I thought I'd check to see if there's anything I can do to cure the pain from teh above.

Comment: It seems that the certificate contains `Basic Constraints` certificate extension with `isCA` bit set to `True`. It should be either, absent or the bit set to `False`. But you can ignore this error in testing environment. In production, you should have proper CA-issued certificate.

Comment: Crypt32 is correct in that you can ignore this warning when testing (it is just a warning). Or in other words: it is very likely that the (unknown) errors in your application have a different cause.